# Compiz grid plugin places window on two virtual desktops

Tags: unity, compiz

When I use the "Put Right" function of the Compiz grid plugin to maximize a window on the right half of a desktop, a two-pixel stripe of the window ends up on the next virtual desktop just to the right. The window then appears on two desktops simultaneously, which is a bit inconvenient to handle. "Put Left" works fine, interestingly.

I run 11.10 with unity. Any idea if that is a known bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Compiz Grid plugin has some *difficulties* with window geometry and especially right side edges. There are a few similar bug reports:

- [windows near to the right edge of the screen inhibit the unity toolbar on the next rightmost screen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/726846)
- [Grid plugin places windows incorrectly when dragged to right edge](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/901530)

And for a collection: [Launchpad Bug #774986](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/774986/comments/2)

I can confirm that I also get a 2px overlay on my right monitor by „putting a window right” on the left monitor.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. I'll just look at the bug reports for further information.

Comment: Disable auto-hiding the Launcher, at Settings -> Apperance -> Behavior.